# Crash when attempting to save a String to UserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this line of code to save a String to UserDefaults,

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(userSelected, forKey: "myKeyString")
```

However it results in the crash,

```
[User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object (Function) as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key myKeyString
```

Why?

Comment: The error message would have told you that whatever you think you are storing, it's not a String.

Comment: For the record, I disagree with the downvotes.  I'm an experienced developer, but new to Swift, and I ended up puzzled by this - I think the crash message is less than clear until you realise what the problem is.  I reckon I won't be the only person to require help, and therefore believe that posting the issue will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the heavy clue was in the error message above. userSelected is actually a function that returns the currently selected user (via a Picker) as a String.  I had failed to add the () to invoke the function, so the reference was actually to a func.  However, this compiled just fine, and it wasn't until run-time that things went awry.

The fixed code is as follows,

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(userSelected(), forKey: "myKeyString")
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Reading the whole error message is always a good place to start.